# How to only log in using admin. Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, authentication

Email:

Invalid email!

Password:

Password need 10 characters!

Submit

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you comment your code, please? And give the behavior that is causing the problem, please? Ty

Comment: Hi, I am totally new at this and thank you. What do you need me to comment? As for now I don´t know how to do it. I want John Doe and Kylie Johnson to be the only ones that can log in. Right now anyone can log in to my dashboard.

Comment: Authentication validation should never be done client side, if you care about serious authentication at all.  It is **very very** easy to inspect code, set breakpoints, find your credentials in source files.

Comment: I only been programming for 4 months... so I am totally new at this. Trying to learn.

Comment: Then my suggestion would be to put this on the back burner, and you need to start considering what your options are for authenticating users on the server side.

Comment: I been working on this for 2 weeks. I don´t want to do it all over again. Im using json to get users to the dashboard and I can display each user using ID. Now, I only want to be able to log in with this emails and passwords. If you could help me with a solution I would be very happy.

Comment: @ProGraMMing, if your question change you need to create a separate thread for it and not edit it like you have done..Your previous question might be useful to others

Comment: @ProGraMMing why did you remove all your code in your last edit? Without it, this question becomes useless in the context of helping others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to do a serverside authentication, but if you are practicing the authentication from mockdata then you can do the following on your onSubmit:

```
onSubmit(): void {
  var res = this.authservice.admins.filter(data => data.email === this.model.email && data.password === this.model.password);

  if (res.length > 0) {
    this.authservice.adminFull = true; 
    this.authservice.isUserLoggedIn = true;
    this.route.navigate(['/dashboard']); 
    this.text = null;
  }else{
    //do whatever you want for unauthenticated
    alert('user not found');
  }


}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and let you know if it worked!